# Constructor on Injected class not getting called Laravel IOC

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, inversion-of-control

I am injecting the InvoiceService in the testclass. Test class calling the create method of the invoice service..
Constructor  of the injected class not getting called because of this $repo is null create is failing. 
Any help is appreciated.

```
$this->app->singleton(
    'App\Models\Subscription\Interfaces\IInvoiceService',
    'App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService'
);



class InvoiceService implements  IInvoiceService
{

    protected $repo;


    public function _construct(){

        $this->app = App::getFacadeRoot();

        $this->repo = $this->app['repo'];


    }
    public function Create($array)
    {
    $this->repo->insert($array); // //$this->repo is null as Constructor not getting called
    }
 }


 class TestClass 

 {
    protected $InvoiceService;
    public function _construct(IInvoiceService $InvoiceService){

            $this->InvoiceService =$InvoiceService

    }

    public create($input) {

        this->InvoiceService->create($input);  // This is failing
    }
 }
```

Comment: What should repo bee? which class

Comment: $app->singleton('repo', function($app)
{
    return new RepoManager($app);
});

Comment: The syntax you are using for resolving the repo, i have not seen (thou it can be correct). What happens if you exchange the line with. $this->repo = resolve('repo'); then you can avoid saving app property too :)

Comment: Problem is constructor ever getting called. Even i replace it with resolve it won't help as constructor not getting called.

Comment: you are not even using constructor

Answer (score 0):

To override default functionality you use __ "two underscores", in your example you are only using one.

```
_construct()
```

Should be.

```
__construct()
```